# Replacing specific items within observable arrays in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am quite new to knockout.js, and I am enjoying learning how to make interfaces with it. But I have a bit of a wall while trying to make my interface more efficient. What I am trying to achieve is remove only the elements selected by **$('.document_checkbox').serializeArray(),** which contains the revision_id. I will then re-add the entries to the view model with a modified call to self.getDocument(), passing only the modified records which will be re-added. Can anyone help me how to remove the entries from the arrays based on the 'revision_id' values of **$('.document_checkbox').serializeArray()**
?

```
function Document(data) {
    this.line_id = data.line_id
    this.revision_id = ko.observable(data.revision_id);
    this.status_id = ko.observable(data.status_id);
}

function DocumentViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.documents = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.getDocument = function(){
        //Reset arrays
        self.documents.removeAll();
        //Dynamically build section arrays
        $.getJSON("/Documentation/Get-Section", function(allData) {
            $.map(allData, function(item) {
                var section = { name: item.array_name, display_name: item.display_name, documents: ko.observableArray([])};
                self.documents.push(section);
            })
            //Add document objects to the arrays
            $.getJSON("/Documentation/Get-Document", function(allData){
                $.map(allData, function(item) { 
                var section = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.documents(), function(documentSection) {
                    return documentSection.name === item.array_name;
                });
                section.documents.push(new Document(item));
                });
            });
        });
    }


    self.updateStatusBatch = function(data,event){
        $.post('/Documentation/Update-Status-Batch',
        { 
            revision_id : $('.document_checkbox').serializeArray(),
            status_id : event.currentTarget.value
        }).done(
        function(){
              //This is where I get confused.
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Would you be willing to add your html and bindings to this question?

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the /Documentation/Update-Status-Batch in order that it returns the deleted item id. So you will be able to remove it on the client side.

Try this "done" function:

```
function(removedItemId) {
    self.documents.remove(function(doc){ 
        return doc.status_id == removedItemId;
    })
}
```

Take a look at the [remove](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html) function.

I hope it helps.